# Nested Func<T, object> in a Generic Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq, generics, delegates, extension-methods

I have an interface defined like so:

```
public interface IEntityUnitOfWork : IEntityModelUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    IQueryable<T> IncludeProperties<T>(IQueryable<T> theQueryable, params Func<T, object>[] toInclude)
        where T : class, new();
}
```

...which allows me to write code like this:

```
var foo = MyUnitOfWork.IncludeProperties(
    MyUnitOfWork.MyQueryable,
    p=>p.MyProperty1,
    p=>p.MyProperty2,
    ...
    p=>p.MyPropertyN);
```

With some mojo on the implementation, this works pretty swimmingly.  But it seems awkward.  I think I should be able to write this cleaner, so I can use this sort of format:

```
var foo = MyUnitOfWork.Fetch(
    f=>f.MyQueryable,
    p=>p.MyProperty1,
    p=>p.MyProperty2,
    ...
    p=>p.MyPropertyN);
```

So I wrote an extension method like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Fetch<T>(
    this IEntityUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
    Func<IEntityUnitOfWork, IQueryable<T>> queryable,
    params Func<T, object>[] toInclude) where T:class, new()
{
    var q = queryable.Target as IQueryable<T>;
    foreach (var p in toInclude)
    {
        q = unitOfWork.IncludeProperties(q, new[] { p });
    }
    return q ;
}
```

This builds, and the Intellisense works as I would expect it to, but of course when actually trying to use it, it fails with a `NullReferenceException`.  The `queryable.Target`, which I assumed would be the `IQueryable<T>` that I was trying to reference, does not appear to be what I assumed, and I don't see an obvious other choice from my Intellisense/ Quickwatch options.

How do I set that `q` value to be the `IQueryable<T>` property off my `IEntityUnitOfWork` that I want to reference in the following statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after more tinkering, it looks like I didn't want the `Target` property of the function, but rather the `Invoke()` method:

```
var q = queryable.Invoke(unitOfWork);
```

after a bit of optimization, I made it look like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Fetch<T>(
    this IEntityUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
    Func<IEntityUnitOfWork, IQueryable<T>> queryable,
    params Func<T, object>[] toInclude) where T : class, new()
{
    var q = queryable.Invoke(unitOfWork);
    return unitOfWork.IncludeProperties(q, toInclude);
}
```

...and this works exactly as desired.

Comment: That is indeed valid, but the conventional way of writing this is just `queryable(unitOfWork)`. You may also want to rename that parameter: it isn't a queryable any longer.

Comment: @hvd, Good to know, thanks.  Can you elucidate on "isn't a queryable any longer"?  That suggests it was, but now it isn't?

Comment: You originally had `IQueryable<T> theQueryable`, and in that case, it really is a queryable. When you have `Func<..., IQueryable<T>>` you don't have a queryable, you have a function that when called returns a queryable.